# Send Mail Youtrack Workflow Helpdesk

Tags: javascript, youtrack

```
var entities = require('@jetbrains/youtrack-scripting-api/entities');
var notifications = require('@jetbrains/youtrack-scripting-api/notifications');

exports.rule = entities.Issue.onChange({
  title: 'Send Email Notification',
  guard: function(ctx) {
    return true;
  },
  action: function(ctx) {
    var issue = ctx.issue;
    var recipients = ['example@test.de'];

    var emailTemplate = '<html><body>' +
                        '<p>Issue {{issue.id}} wurde aktualisiert.</p>' +
                        '<p>Zusammenfassung: {{issue.summary}}</p>' +
                        '<p>Status: {{issue.State.name}}</p>' +
                        '</body></html>';

    var email = notifications.email({
      to: recipients,
      subject: 'Aktualisierung von Issue ' + issue.id,
      body: emailTemplate
    });
    notifications.send(email);
  }
});
```

I try to send an email to the creator of the ticket with the content of the comment when a comment has been added to the ticket. However, I always get the error message
TypeError: notifications.email is not a function or
Message contains an undefined list of recipient email addresses or the list is empty.
What did I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be notifications.sendEmail().
Here is an example you can refer to:

```js
var issue = ctx.issue;
if (issue.comments.added.isNotEmpty()) {
  var authorName = issue.comments.added.first().author.fullName;
  var message = {
    fromName: authorName,
    to: ['user1@jetbrains.com', 'user2@jetbrains.com'],
    cc: ['user1@jetbrains.com', 'user2@jetbrains.com'],
    bcc: ['user1@jetbrains.com', 'user2@jetbrains.com'],
    subject: 'New comment in ' + issue.id,
    headers: {
      'X-Custom-Header': 'Important value'
    },
    body: [
      '<div style="font-family: sans-serif">',
      '  <div style="padding: 10px 10px; font-size: 13px; border-bottom: 1px solid #D4D5D6;">',
      '    New comment was added in issue ' + issue.id + ' by ' + authorName,
      '  </div>',
      '<\div>'
    ].join('\n')
  };
  notifications.sendEmail(message, issue);
}
```

Also, here is the corresponding documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/devportal/v1-notifications.html#functions

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :) It is working perfect